# WooCommerce - woocommerce_rest_cannot_view - Status 401

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-rest-api

I have generated a consumer key and consumer secret. The website has SSL installed. I have also installed plugins required for JSON and REST services. This is how the url looks like:

```
https://<url>/wp-json/wc/v1/products
```

When I am trying to get(GET) the product details using Basic Auth by using POSTMAN, a Chrome plugin, I get a JSON response like:

```
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

I have both the READ and WRITE permissions corresponding to the Consumer key.

Comment: Problem solved at this link :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102194/woocommerce-rest-api-woocommerce-rest-cannot-view

Comment: Problem solved at this link :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102194/woocommerce-rest-api-woocommerce-rest-cannot-view

Answer (score 67):

The 401 error you are getting is because you are using basic auth even though your website is not secure (does not have https).

The solution in postman is to use OAuth 1.0. Just add the consumer key and consumer secret and send the request.

Comment: Wonderful! It worked great for me. I was struggling so much with that aspect.

Comment: I tried this way, but I still have the same result. I have an https website

Comment: @Rom-888 did you select the Add Auth data to: Request Body/ Request URL?

Comment: WooCommerce wiki REST part put the wrong option that so many developers have this issue with basic AUTH

Comment: It works in postman but when I send the request using GuzzleHttp it gives the same error as above

Comment: @aliencity I hade the exact same problem. Postman working fine, laravel w. guzzle client failing. After changing "->get('http://..." to "->get('https://.." it works as expected! *Note that you have to serve your wp installation over https though. In my case that was easy with MAMP

Answer (score 20):

I met same problem.

Here is how I solve it:

```
require "woocommerce_api"

woocommerce = WooCommerce::API.new(
  "https://example.com",
  "consumer_key",
  "consumer_secret",
  {
    wp_json: true,
    version: "wc/v1",
    query_string_auth: true
  }
)
```

The key is `query_string_auth: true`
you need to force basic authentication as query string true under `HTTPS`

Comment: @Aloha where am I supposed to use it? please explain in details your answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is how i stopped worrying and moved on.

In short, the woocommerce rest controllers pretty much all have a  `SOMEWPRESTCLASS::get_item_permissions_check()` method which in turn calls `wc_rest_check_post_permissions()` to decide if it returns that error;

So you hook into that and validate whichever way you want:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 'my_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 90, 4 );

function my_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions( $permission, $context, $object_id, $post_type  ){
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is actually not very good because this way you open the door to everyone!

Comment: although i know this risk with this, I cant find any other solution right now, thanks for this. will use as a temporary fix

Answer (score 5):

Try this, I had the same issue with the automattic/woocommerce library and I just got it working by appending the customer_key and customer_secret to the query.

```
$woocommerce->get("customers/$userId?consumer_key={$this->key}&consumer_secret={$this->secret}");
```

---

**Quick Edit**

---

The above method works but I found a better solution for the automattic/woocommerce library.

Set **query_string_auth** to **true**

Had to dig into the code to find this setting.

Found nothing on it in the docs

```
return new Client($this->url, $this->key, $this->secret, [
    "query_string_auth" => true
]);
```

Comment: After a long time I found your solution setting the query_string_auth to true and finally I fixed it! Thanks a lot man ;)

Comment: @dieter Can i know which file append these codes please

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this. Apparently something was funny with how curl was handling the url, so I had to encapsulate it in double quotes.

This doesn't work:
curl https://www.my-site.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_40097dbc2844ce7712e1820bcadf0149c2bedegh&consumer_secret=cs_ab57e19263af0b9ab4c596c310f1e7904bb20123

This does work:
curl **"**https://www.my-site.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_40097dbc2844ce7712e1820bcadf0149c2bedegh&consumer_secret=cs_ab57e19263af0b9ab4c596c310f1e7904bb20123**"**

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved by adding this line below to the end of .htaccess file

All you need to add this line to .htaccess , this work with me

**SetEnv HTTPS on**

And make sure  use **OAuth 1.0** for Authorization

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Trying to help others:
I was struggling with the 401 response while trying to CURL, and also with VBA trying to request as content-type "application/json"
However, I was able to pull a valid response by just entering this in my browser address bar:
https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=ck_blahblah&consumer_secret=cs_blahblah

Following this line of thought, I went back to my VBA app and changed the content type to "application/text" and was able to pull a valid response text with response code 200. 
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: +1 because this is how I get Postman to send the request. Thanks! on http It was working with OAuth 1.0. With production server on https it works with this. Really queer!

Answer (score 4):

You can try Oauth 1.0 with postman:

[image: here is screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this, I was getting the exact same error message as OP. I was using https and OAuth 1. The problem ended up being the domain. I was trying to access `example.com` when the correct domain for the site was `www.example.com`.

This URL returns 401 woocommerce_rest_cannot_view error:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products
```

This URL works and returns results:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products
```

Comment: Exactly this was my problem too. Make sure you check www in your request URL

Answer (score 2):

Try making the request using query parameter, like this:

```
https://www.exemple.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_01234567890&consumer_secret=cs_01234567890
```

here: `https://www.exemple.com` you'll need to fill your url domain.

**here**: `consumer_key and consumer_secret` is your **ck** and **cs** that was previous genereted on **WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > REST API**

Comment: This worked for me (y)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified answer to Quickredfox's anwer:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 'my_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 90, 4);

function my_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions($permission, $context, $object_id, $post_type) {
    if($_GET['consumer_key'] == 'asdfghj' && $_GET['consumer_secret'] == 'qwerty') {
        return true;
    }

    return $permission;
}
```

The downside to this is that the flexibility of adding and revoking access for users using a gui is lost. However, if nothing else works and you just can't figure out why, this will work and does not expose the API to the whole world.

Oh, and this requires passing the key and secret as parameters a la:

```
https://foo.bar.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/123&consumer_key=asdfghj&consumer_secret=qwerty
```

This will work without https, but if you use it without https, remember that any credentials you send along with your request will be sent in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

For local development (localhost) you can also use Basic Auth (e.g. for Postman) instead of Consumer Key & Consumer Secret. It works seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to function.php to fix the problem:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 'my_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 90, 4 );

function my_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions( $permission, $context, $object_id, $post_type  ){
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt this disable any form of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

in node js code would be

```js
const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;
 
const api = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: "http://example.com",
  consumerKey: "ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  consumerSecret: "cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  queryStringAuth: true,
  version: "wc/v3"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes an error with wordpress htaccess configuration (only if you are accessing website by https).

For some reason woocommerce want you to authorize with basic authentication when your are connecting through https which some hosting blocks so you need to unlock it.

you need to change

`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

To

`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]`