# WooCommerce API gives 401 in Google App Engine but works (200 OK) in local env

Tags: python, google-app-engine, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I’m writing an app that allows users to integrate their WooCommerce stores with my site. I’m using the [Python wrapper for the WooCommerce REST API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WooCommerce) and my app is hosted on Google App Engine. Here’s my code to call the Woocommerce API. (I’m using https to connect to all the WooCommerce stores)

```
 def request_woo_api(self, user, request_url):
        wcapi = API(
            url=user.woo_url,
            consumer_key=user.woo_consumer_key,
            consumer_secret=user.woo_consumer_secret,
            wp_api=True,
            version="wc/v2",
            query_string_auth=True
            )
        resp = wcapi.get(request_url).json()
        return resp
```

I get a 200 OK response when I test my code on my dev machine. But when I deploy my code to Google App Engine I get a 401 response for **some** WooCommerce stores.

```
{u'message': u'Sorry, you cannot list resources.', u'code': u'woocommerce_rest_cannot_view', u'data': {u'status': 401}}
```

I read [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-requests) in this documentation that Google App Engine appends a value (`AppEngine-Google; (http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: <application_id>)`) to the `user-agent` header for all outbound requests. And I think this is the problem because I tried calling a woocommerce api from my local machine and it worked, but when I appended this value to my header the same endpoint gave the 401 error.

```
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'WooCommerce API Client-Python/1.2.1'} 
>>> result = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
>>> print result.json() 
[{u'date_completed_gmt': None, u'date_modified_gmt': u'2017-11-30T18:13:59', u'payment_method': u'.......
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'WooCommerce API Client-Python/1.2.1; AppEngine-Google; (http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: 123)'} 
>>> result = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
>>> print result.json() 
{u'message': u'Sorry, you cannot list resources.', u'code': u'woocommerce_rest_cannot_view', u'data': {u'status': 401}}
```

The fact that this happens only for a couple of WooCommerce sites and not the others makes me think that these users might have a WooCommerce setting/plugin extension/security setting that is causing this isssue. Is there any way to-

1. Stop GAE from appending to this header to outbound requests?
2. Turn off a plugin or setting that prevents the WooCoomerce store from filtering requests based on the `user-agent` value? (I can request the users to change the security settings to their site)

Please help.

( I have already tried the following and it hasn't helped:

- Tried using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead of [Python wrapper for the WooCommerce REST API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WooCommerce) and I get the same behaviour; works in local env but returns the 401 error on GAE.
- Added the `query_string_auth=True` and also tried adding `verify_ssl=False` (just in case the users were using a self-signed test site)
- Tried adding a `_method=GET` query parameter as suggested [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15404)
- Tried setting the `content-type` to "application/text" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186757/woocommerce-woocommerce-rest-cannot-view-status-401) )

**UPDATE**

Upon further investigation I found that the WooCommerce store server ignores the query string parameters.
I'm able to get a response if I don’t send the “query_string_auth=true” setting. But the store ignores ALL query parameters. The query_string_auth parameter sends the consumer_key and secret in a query string. When I remove it, it goes as a auth header. Now that I'm sending it as a auth header it responds. But it ignores query parameters. My guess is that the server ignores ALL query parameters. That explains why I was getting the 401 in the first place. (Because we sent the key and secret as a query parameter). And this only happens when I send the "User-Agent: AppEngine-Google;"

Example:

```
store_url = "https://teststore.com"
endpoint = "/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?per_page=1"
auth = ("ck_xxxxxxxxxxx", "cs_xxxxxxxxxxx")
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'WooCommerce API Client-Python/1.2.1'}
url = '{}/{}'.format(store_url, endpoint)
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth, headers=headers)
print response.json()
```

This returns exactly one order.

```
store_url = "https://teststore.com"
endpoint = "/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?per_page=1"
auth = ("ck_xxxxxxxxxxx", "cs_xxxxxxxxxxx")
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'WooCommerce API Client-Python/1.2.1; AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: 123)'}
url = '{}/{}'.format(store_url, endpoint)
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth, headers=headers)
print response.json()
```

This returns 10 orders (default page size is 10)

But I still have no idea why some stores do this or how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my problem. 
**It was a WP Engine setting that was causing the problem**. My app is hosted on Google App Engine and it adds a header value “AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid:” to the User-Agent header in ALL requests. WP Engine redirects requests from bots to a cached version of the page. It detects bots by parsing the User-Agent header. When it finds 'Google' in the value, it assumes that it is a Googlebot and redirects it to a cached page. And so, it ends up ignoring all the query parameters in the URL (credentials, filter parameters etc).

I didn't need to change my code at all. I simply contacted WP-Engine support and asked them to turn off the user-agent-based bot filter (It is turned on by default) for one of my test WooCommerce sites and it worked!