# WooCommerce REST API "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view "

Tags: rest, api, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

when i paste this link

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=ck_*******************&consumer_secret=cs_********************

it show for me this error message

> {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"D\u00e9sol\u00e9, vous ne pouvez pas lister les ressources.","data":{"status":401}}

by the way the cosumers key & secret are correct

Answer (score 1):

Your connection must be throw https 
and add this lines to your woocommerce init :

```
{
....
      verifySsl: false,
      queryStringAuth: true
}
```

every post request require ssl

dublicate from this link
[Ionic 3 WP-REST API Post request 401 (unauthorized) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104346/ionic-3-wp-rest-api-post-request-401-unauthorized-error/52156298#52156298)
&
[WooCommerce REST API "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102194/woocommerce-rest-api-woocommerce-rest-cannot-view)

Comment: `queryStringAuth: true` was the solution for me

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about wordpress. I am unable to find woocommerce init. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 possible solutions:

1. Add the following variable in the index.php page of your WordPress installation (Worked for me on my localhost without having to restart the server):

`$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';  //------> Add this line under the line that says: define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );`

2. Set the environment variable in the .htaccess file when using Apache:

`SetEnv HTTPS on`

Answer (score 0):

401 is unauthorized error

if key and secret are correct, it could be todo with SSL

other people report similar problems

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/19649

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding this line below to the end of .htaccess file

All you need to add this line to .htaccess , this work with me

**SetEnv HTTPS on**

And make sure use **OAuth 1.0** for Authorization

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add false in end of creating RestAPI like this...

RestAPI rest = new RestAPI(URL, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, false);

it should by "authorizedHeader"

answer from https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET/issues/211

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions helped me, so I deleted my previous API credentials and created new ones. This made the change for me.

I don't want to say "just delete your credentials" as you have to make sure to not break any necessary connections, please note that! I'm just sharing my experience on this.