# Ionic 3 WP-REST API Post request 401 (unauthorized) error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing a simple application to create a user in Wordpress (woocommerce) through wp-rest api. 
but when I try to create a new customers it shows 401 Unauthorised error in console. heres is my code for request.

```js
signup(){

    let customerData = {
      customer : {}
    }

    customerData.customer = {
      "email": this.newUser.email,
      "first_name": this.newUser.first_name,
        ...
      "billing_address": {
        "first_name": this.newUser.first_name,
        ...
      },
      "shipping_address": {
        "first_name": this.newUser.first_name,
          ...

      }
    }

    if(this.billing_shipping_same){
      this.newUser.shipping_address = this.newUser.shipping_address;
    }
    this.WooCommerce.postAsync('customers', customerData).then( (data) => {

      console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
    })

  }
```

by the way the key client & secret are correct 
[image]

Comment: This might mean that you're in fact unauthorized to post data to this API. Aren't you supposed to pass an Authorization Header along with this request?

Comment: how to pass it ? and where ?

Comment: How do you know that api is working ?

Comment: post your `WooCommerce` class.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `https` connection, add the following lines to your woocommerce init :

```
verifySsl: false,
queryStringAuth: true
```

Any `post` request requires an `https` connection.