# woocommerce rest api - did not show product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am setting up a new website on WordPress with woocommerce, I need to show products on my application so, I am using Woocommerce Rest API but did not work 
i am using PHP 7.0, WordPress version 5.0.9 & woocommerce version 3.5+

I am trying these link

http://solskjermern.no/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=16&consumer_key=ck_672be4cfbe61b227acfb8669d042b6b69dd4621a&consumer_secret=cs_2efb814974cb7c89285b9ff06986c9eee1055121

it keeps showing me this msg in JSON format

{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
but i want all those products who have category id 16

Comment: Possible duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186757/woocommerce-woocommerce-rest-cannot-view-status-401

Comment: not duplicate because I need in a link not in code

Answer (score 0):

is the SSL certificate valid and the API key associated with a user with Admin capabilities?

Cheers,
Francesco