# 401 Error on rest apis on default woocommerce API requests

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Their is a strange 401 error comes in basic rest APIs.
For example:

> https://parosi.techchef.org/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?consumer_key=ck_f76c28eae983eb9b237d6bb81dd5b6c1ee35d16f

I have already checked and trouble shoot following steps.

```
1- Enable the legacy REST API is checked
2- I have made new rest api and applied the same consumer key
3- I created new admin and tried
4- I replace htaccess with default wordpress
5- I have upgrade both wordpress and woocommerce version to latest
6- I have disabled all other plugins
```

But none of the things work still, rest every thing is working fine but rest-API authentication for woocommerce does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution below, posted here:
[WooCommerce - woocommerce_rest_cannot_view - Status 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186757/woocommerce-woocommerce-rest-cannot-view-status-401)

> ```
> The 401 error you are getting is because you are using basic auth even though your website is not secure (does not have https).
>
> The solution in postman is to use OAuth 1.0. Just add the consumer key and consumer secret and send the request.
> ```

Comment: Totally worked with me, I'm using HTTP, not HTTPS. Thanks.